# Javascript round number after the . to 3 digits only

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a variable with a result that looks like this:

```
myresult = 14.4565576
```

I need to round the decimal after the DOT to only 3 numbers.

For example I need to round this:

```
14.4565576
```

to this:

```
14.456
```

How can I do this?

Comment: ```myresult.toFixed(3)```

Comment: The proposed answer for `1.2` will give you `1.200`, not sure if that's what you want. I don't think you've made too much research btw, check this threat for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to at most 2 decimal places, if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method

```js
const number = 14.4565576
console.log(number.toFixed(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to use for specific case only then you can use as:**

```
let number = 123.456789;
let roundedNumber = number.toFixed(3);
console.log(roundedNumber);  // Output: "123.457"
```

**But if you want to make it more dynamic and reusable you can make common function as:**

```
function toFixed(number, digits){
    return parseFloat(number.toFixed(digits));
}
```